# Help needed bubbling up relevant records with most recent date

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I've got 5 records in Lucene index.

- a.Record 1 contains--tax
  analysis.Date field value is March
  2009

  b.Record 2 contains--Senior tax
  analyst.Date field value is Aug 2009

  c.Record 3 contains--Senior tax
  analyst.Date field value is July 2009

  d.Record 4 contains--tax analyst.Date
  field value is Feb 2009

  e.Record 5 contains--Senior tax
  analyst.Date field value is Oct 2009

If the input keyword is senior tax analyst,then search results should come up in the following order:

- a.Record 5--because this record is
  has got the most recent date and has
  got the matching phrase

  b.Record 2--because this record has
  got second most recent date and has
  got the matching phrase

  c.Record 3--because this record has
  got third most recent date and has
  got the matching phrase

  d.Record 4

  e.Record 1

Basically,I want to show the most relevant records grouped by date and sorted in descending order by date.And then, I want to show remaining records sorted by descending value of relevancy.
How do i achieve this with Lucene?

Please help.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do this by first collecting the search results and then sorting them using a CustomSorter. [This blog entry](http://blog.tremend.ro/2007/05/17/a-z-0-9-custom-sorting-in-lucene/) explains custom sorting in Lucene Java. You have to translate this to .Net, using [.Net's ScoreDocComparator](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/docs/2.1/Lucene.Net.Search.ScoreDocComparator.html). Your compare() method will have to get the date fields from the documents and compare them. I would first try to get the proper order for the exact matches (Record 5, 2, and 3). Later, you can use the match as well in your comparator. You can generalize my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517/lucene-exact-ordering) in order to do this.