# How to apply default sorting in lucene on equal scores?

Tags: lucene, sorting

Good day,

If I have for example the documents which have the following fields

```
Person_name - Birthday
Jordan - 2009-06-15
Marc - 2009-01-01
Marcos - 2009-01-01
Marcissh_something_something - 2009-06-15
Marcos - 2009-12-31
```

And upon searching for Person_name:Marc* I got the following scores (scores here are hypothetical)

```
Person_name - Birthday - Score
Jordan - 2009-06-15 - 0.0
Marc - 2009-01-01 - 1.0
Marcos - 2009-01-01 - 0.8
Marcissh_something_something - 2009-06-15 - 0.1
Marcos - 2009-12-31 - 0.8
```

How can I retrieve the result such that the result is first sorted by relevancy, and then assuming same relevancy (score) sort by birthday descendingly....such that the result is

```
Person_name - Birthday - Score
Marc - 2009-01-01 - 1.0
Marcos - 2009-12-31 - 0.8
Marcos - 2009-01-01 - 0.8
Marcissh_something_something - 2009-06-15 - 0.1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to recommend a ScoreDocComparator, but I see it is deprecated now. You can use a [FieldComparator](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/FieldComparator.html). You need to create a [TopFieldCollector](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/TopFieldCollector.html) and define its [Sort](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/Sort.html) according to your wishes. I believe this is rather new, as I could not find a good example.

Comment: Since I'm using lucene 2.4.1, I'll probably go with ScoreDocComparator...but how do I use it exactly? :-)

Comment: In that case, please see my answer to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517/lucene-exact-ordering

Answer (score 1):

Try to examine the search results and then sort those with equal score yourself. You can use a comparator for this which compares the score and then the natural fields of the search results.